Can my uncle sponsor my trip for my assessment
I received an invitation from the UK Royal Navy for the next phase of the Recruitment process (4 days assessment). I'm unemployed but I have 19 sheep, 3 acres of cassava farm, 2 plot of land, a fiancee and two kids, I call. With this I will be start selling them next year. My uncle will be sponsoring my 4 days assessment trip. I work for my uncle as he has taken care of me since father died at elementary school. Can my uncle sponsor my trip without me adding any bank statement

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

While this prior question concerns a UK visa refusal, rather than a refusal from Canada, the analysis presented in the answers will be the same for your application.

There was a mistake in typing. It's been edited now

Selling sheep may not we wise. Also with positive assessment, you do not know how much you can get further in training, and also after that.... things happen. You may be the strongest man in the world, but you do not know if your body can survive without sun, in humid and very noisy place. And beware of scams (navy will not requires money for you, and they should provide all things for your stay.

I'm not a native english speaker, but to me the text reads as if you intend to sell your fiancee and the two kids. Also you say that your uncle will be sponsoring your trip and then then proceeds to ask if he can.


Can my uncle sponsor my trip without me adding any bank statement?

Yes, he can do that, and in fact I have done exactly that on three occasions. However, bear in mind that even with a credible financial sponsor who can prove sufficient funds, as this question explains the onus is still on you to prove that you meet the rules.
In my case, the person I successfully sponsored had a stable job for which he was paid in cash and could prove it, and had dependents (an elderly parent and a child) in his home country. You say you are unemployed, but that you work for your uncle; you also mention that you have two children. Those ties to home might be enough but you will need to provide evidence to prove them.
Finally, as @Giacomo Catenazzi comments, scams relating to overseas recruitment abound. If you haven’t already done so, you should read this guide to the Royal Navy overseas recruitment programme.

The OP asks if the uncle can do this "without me adding any bank statement". It would be good to address that.

@DJClayworth In what way does my answer not address that?

I just thought maybe something about how the applicant has to say something about his own financial situation, even if he is being sponsored. No worries.
